# Why does IntelliJ gray out types, fields and methods?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: IntelliJ screenshot]

Can somebody explain why IntelliJ grays out types, fields inside methods and how to disable it? In my example words `String`, `length`, `TEST` and `length()` are all grayed out.

IntelliJ version 2021.3.1

Answer (score 2):

This is syntax highlighting.  It is grey for variable names, class names and member names, but can be changed.  You can disable or change the style in the options.

Search for `syntax highlighting` in the options search field, find the entry for your language and modify it.

Comment: I found `Semantic highlighting` option for Java, updated it but it didn't help

Comment: Change the `scheme`, or find each type of syntax item and change it (class fields, variables, etc). You will need to save a custom scheme, there is no way to just disable it across the board